# php mysql_fetch_array reset

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print a list from a mysql database, but the first list item isn't printing because mysql_fetch_array is called twice. I tried reset but it didn't work. What should I do?

```
$current_goam = mysql_real_escape_string($current_goam);
$current_content = mysql_real_escape_string($current_content);

$note_content = mysql_query("select * from notes where title='$current_content' and goam='$current_goam' and user_id='$user_id'");

$note = mysql_fetch_array( $note_content );

if($note['type'] == 'list')
{
    $note_type='list';      
    reset($note);

    print "<table>";
    while($note_info = mysql_fetch_array( $note_content ))
    {
        print "<tr><td>";
           echo $note_info['body'];
            print "</td>";

            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='complete_goal' value='".$note_info['note_id']."'></input></td>";         
         print "</tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";
}   
else{
    echo $note['body'];
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this instead of `reset`

```
mysql_data_seek($note_content, 0);
```

`reset` works for arrays

Comment: Note that if you're using mysqli instead of mysql then you will need to use mysqli_data_seek($note_content, 0);

Answer (score 2):

Try to load data in array and then use it as you whant

```
$records = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($note_content)) {
    $records[] = $r;
}
```